# How to get specific part of url string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is the result of the `console.log` below:

```
console.log('subscribe:', event.url);
"https://hooks.stripe.com/adapter/ideal/redirect/complete/src_1E2lmZHazFCzVZTmhYOsoZbg/src_client_secret_EVnN8bitF0wDIe6XGcZTThYZ?success=true"
```

Where I want to strip `src_1E2lmZHazFCzVZTmhYOsoZbg` and `src_client_secret_EVnN8bitF0wDIe6XGcZTThYZ`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string to a url, read the pathname and than split on `/` and take the last two parts.

```js
var str = "https://hooks.stripe.com/adapter/ideal/redirect/complete/src_1E2lmZHazFCzVZTmhYOsoZbg/src_client_secret_EVnN8bitF0wDIe6XGcZTThYZ?success=true"

const parts = new URL(str).pathname.split('/').slice(-2)
console.log(parts)
```

Comment: whish I could delete my own answer now - Although this will **not work in any IE browser** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

Answer (score 1):

If the query parameter `?success=true` is optional (as in most cases *is*) you could

```js
function getSrcAndSecret (url) {
  const pts = /\/(src_[^/?]+)\/(src_client_secret_[^/?]+)/.exec(url);
  return {
    src: pts && pts[1] || "",
    secret: pts && pts[2] || ""
  } 
}

// Demo:
const test1 = getSrcAndSecret("https://hooks.stripe.com/adapter/ideal/redirect/complete/src_1E2lmZHazFCzVZTmhYOsoZbg/src_client_secret_EVnN8bitF0wDIe6XGcZTThYZ?success=true");
const test2 = getSrcAndSecret("https://hooks.stripe.com/adapter/ideal/redirect/complete/src_1E2lmZHazFCzVZTmhYOsoZbg/src_client_secret_EVnN8bitF0wDIe6XGcZTThYZ");
const test3 = getSrcAndSecret("https://hooks.stripe.com/adapter/ideal/redirect/complete");

console.log(test1, test2, test3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = "https://hooks.stripe.com/adapter/ideal/redirect/complete/src_1E2lmZHazFCzVZTmhYOsoZbg/src_client_secret_EVnN8bitF0wDIe6XGcZTThYZ?success=true";


const res = url.split(/\?|\//g).filter(el => el.startsWith("src"));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  const [a, b] = event.url.split("?")[0].split("/").slice(-2);
```